# Watch array inside array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to vuejs & I'm trying make a projects/todo app.
I have an array of projects, each project is an **object** that contains an property **tasks** witch is an array.

see the following to understand more : [open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7uee.png)

as you can see, the sidebar component gets the projects array as a prop, then it creates an other object "grps" witch is basicaly a way to group projects by category.

the problem is : When one of the projects tasks changes grps doesn't change as well.

I tried to use **watch** but it didn't work.

Hope someone can help, tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to `watch` nested data (array or object) you need to set `deep` to `true` in you watcher.

I encourage you to read the official Vuejs doc about watcher : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

In your case you would have something like that :

```
watch: {
  element: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('updated')
    }
  }
}
```